# What is the best way to get rid of plants growing in my walls?

Tags: walls, kitchens

In a rental unit my fiancée just leased, 2 weeks after she moved in, a vine-type weed sprouted from the baseboard in her kitchen. Upon further inspection, I was able to pull about a foot of vine before it snapped, and more vines were found to be growing above her dishwasher. The flooring appears to be a concrete base, no plants are penetrating the visible substructure from outside, and the plant growth appears to be contained between the walls and cabinetry.

Is this something I can take care of, or will I need to call the landlord in to remove the cabinets?

Comment: Rental. That means its someone elses problem. As an aside, any idea what kind of plant? I'd like to hazard a guess that its beans from a kitchen spill that got into the wall.

Comment: Magic beans!!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Call in the landlord.  The plants have to be getting water to grow from some source.  Either it's penetrating the siding of the house, it's found a way into the plumbing system, or there is a leak (e.g. plumbing or roof) that is getting water into the wall.

Comment: Not to mention, it's just plain weird!

Comment: Anybody see that movie "The Ruins"? It the vines start making noises like a cell phone, get out of there!

Answer (score 0):

It rather depends what the 'vine' is as to how easy to deal with it might be, so a photo of it would be useful. Hopefully it's not Japanese Knotweed, which will punch right through solid concrete and grow in your lounge, if its beneath, but that would be the landlord's issue, not yours, though if it is that, your fiancee should move as soon as possible before a forest develops inside the home, as there is no easy effective treatment. Otherwise, some type of bindweed, or possibly Russian Vine, but that can only grow inside if it manages to find a crack or hole to get through, again from outside or underneath the building, and is somewhat easier to deal with. Again, the landlord is responsible for sorting it out.